# react-native redux can't find react

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm trying to implement react-redux in my react-native application.

In my root index, I wrote :

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './src/reducers';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
));
```

And the App looks like this :

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
               ......
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

But Metro server keeps giving me : `[Wed Aug 12 2020 11:06:14.345]  ERROR    ReferenceError: Can't find variable: React`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added the reducers in App.js. And everything is now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import React in root index as well

```
import React from 'react';
```

This is not required in normal scenarios but as you are using jsx tags in root index this is required.
Or you can do the provider setup in App.js

Answer (score 1):

You need this line in the root index file

```
import React from 'react';
```